# Портирование flash -> мобильные устройства (iOS, Android)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mobile-development

Возможно, потребуется портировать приложение, написанное на ActionScript 3 (flash) на мобильные устройства (наверное, i-девайсы). Я никогда девайсами не увлекался и представляю процедуру крайне смутно. Немного погуглил, как-то пока туманно всё..
Кто непосредственно сталкивался, подскажите, пожалуйста, программисту, как это делается? Насколько это долгое и трудоемкое занятие? И что можно почитать по теме?

**upd**: уже точно известно, что ожидается портирование на Андроид и iOS. Так что вопрос становится предметнее.

Answer (score 2):

Я делал так:

- адаптируете (рутовый) основной класс проекта под работу с любым контейнером (платформы);
- под каждую платформу создаете проект в Flash Builder 4.5;
- интегрируете в каждый проект свой класс;
- компилируете (Export Release Build) или дебажите (андроид позволяет сразу запустить в дебаге на устройстве).

Comment: получается, язык тот же может быть использован? т.е. настройки компилятора + платформ-специфик код?
я слыхал, что допустим на айфонах надо переписывать на Си. не?..

Comment: Язык тот же, эпл разрешило ненативный код для эплстор приложений,
причем для iOS два варианта, делать пакет со встроенной виртуальной машиной (сам смутно представляю), или делать пакет для установленного в систему AIR.

Comment: Спасибо, я плюсонул, но ответ пока принимать не буду - хотелось бы больше конкретики услышать (может кто еще напишет).